# Are there any technical benefits to using a JavaScript menu?

Tags: javascript, css

_I've seen both pure CSS menus and JavaScript based menus and I can't see that there is anything gained using JavaScript.

Is there something I'm missing.

The [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=css+menu+vs+javascript) pulls up SO articles from a good while back.

Here is an [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688423/css-menu-vs-javascript-menu) from about 5 years ago.

What is the current state of CSS menus?

Comment: If CSS does everything you need it to do: **fantastic!** Use it! Otherwise: Javascript can do *a lot more* than CSS can.

Comment: I would say there are no benefits, and the one disadvantage is that people can disable Javascript which would render the menu useless.

Comment: **CSS3** = issue with X-browser compatibility - Otherwise Superb! - **JS**: 1.5% planetary visitors have JS disabled - Otherwise... Superb! **Pure CSS** - No transitions and animations (bad UI and UX)

Comment: I'm yet to see a toggle-able menu which is keyboard / screen reader friendly that doesn't use JavaScript.

JavaScript makes accessibility much, much easier.

Comment: If you go the JS route, remember to have non-JS fallbacks to ensure your site is still useable by people with JS disabled and also some search engine spiders still do not execute JS when crawling your site so it may affect SEO also.

Comment: _[Yorkshire Accent]_ **Back in t' day** _[/Yorkshire Accent]_, JavaScript was needed to get around certain things that were impossible with CSS2. Now CSS3 is around and accepted in nearly every browser used, you're far better off using CSS.

Comment: @JamieBarker — It really depends on what you are trying to do. CSS makes click based interactions and timeouts on hover based interactions (which are frequently necessary to avoid introducing accessibility barriers ) hard to impossible to achieve.

Comment: @Quentin that's true if you consider that a technical feature (I see it more as a functional) because OP asks about technical benefits.

Comment: @Quentin Click and hover interactions are quite simple with `:active` and `:hover`. Timeouts can be achieved using [Keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) and [`animation-delay`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp)

Comment: @JamieBarker — `:active` only lasts as long as the mouse button is depressed, so that doesn't help with opening a menu when it is clicked. I'm not sure if `animation-delay` would be sufficient to (for instance) stop a `:hover` based submenu from vanishing while you move the mouse from the menu item to the submenu, I'd love a demo to show otherwise. (Last time I seriously looked at CSS for this, every solution required that you very carefully tracked the mouse within the menu item onto the sub menu — surprising for many users, difficult to impossible for people with motor skill issues).

Comment: NB: The above becomes a major issue when the submenu pops out to the side of the previous menu. It's less of a problem (although still one for narrow menus) when it drops straight down).

Comment: @Quentin this issue has actually got me thinking. Of course the click needs `:focus` to work too (http://jsfiddle.net/av7f2L9m/). I'm guessing you are referring to a sub menu that has been absolutely positioned away from the main menu? I'll draw up an example.

Comment: @Quentin http://jsfiddle.net/6x8g6bLk/3/ - This basically works. It does the "un-hover" animation at the beginning so when the page loads they are visible for 3 seconds, but that _could_ actually be helpful to some people. Other than that, it works. I've created [this SO question] to see if anyone has any ideas to get around the animation starting upon page load

Comment: @Quentin Realised you could hover over it on its own so a small improvement was needed: http://jsfiddle.net/6x8g6bLk/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want something that can't be done with CSS, you **gain absolutely nothing** by using JS instead of CSS.

JS was the way to do animated things before CSS3 brought its transitions and animations, and is now becoming a standard because it's simpler and performs better (in those few things it can do).

Comment: How about the case where CSS3 is not available, in an older browser?

Comment: @cadegalt According to this, it's IE10+: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: @Archer, how about people who disable JS? Same thing, you have fallbacks... in CSS3 case, the transition won't play, but it would jump to the final value - I think it's a no big deal for old browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, can't wait to hear the brilliant reason...

Comment: Yeah, fair comment.  Less likely, but I get your point.